# Advise Regarding Backend Development

Tags: backend

I know this question is novice but I really want help here.
I have been covering Databases and learning MySQL, MongoDB and learnt HTML, CSS and Javascript. Did some basic projects with NodeJS and learnt React Framework.

But everywhere I go to, I see this HTTPS, OS, API, Caching, Sockets, Servers etc. I am really not able to understand from where I can start learning.

I have learnt JAVA before all this, and pretty much know every basic things. I want to choose my backend language as JAVA but I really need a guidance as to how can I start or from where?

I tried to understand this [roadmap](https://roadmap.sh/backend) here but it is overwhelming.

Please people it will be much helpful if you can help me out here.

Comment: Learning on your own is really challenging. Do you have the chance to get a good formal education? That should teach all of those topics.

Comment: No, actually going through on my own.

Comment: Do you realize that you are basically trying to get a college level education by looking at an internet page? I'm not sure that is a viable option. There is a reason why teaching institutions exist. If for whatever reason you have no access to formal education, can you at least access online courses? They are no replacement, but at least they offer some structured learning.

Comment: I am going through courses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Learn Spring. That is generally the industry baseline for Java web backends.**

The HTTPS, OS, servers,etc stuff is very broad and only a small portion of that is relevant to purely backend development, with most of it actually part of devops (which could be part of a developer job, but often is a small portion). Learning Spring will teach you about APIs, sockets, and caching, at least in practice.

That is where I would start.

Comment: Thank you so much. I will start looking in Spring than.